# Помогите определиться с правильным адаптером

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток всем! Есть дизайн активити. Основная часть представляет собой список или таблицу. Я склоняюсь ближе к варианту таблицы. Картинки-превью в первой колонке, название и дата - во второй, а кол-во картинок в каждом документе - в треьей. Но для меня немного пока сложно придумать, как в одной ячейке показать сразу 2 строки текста. Причём эти 2 строки разного стиля. Скрин дизайна прилагаю. Надеюсь хотя бы просто на совет.

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listview + обычный адаптер. Посмотрите на этот [урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html) и [этот](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter.html).

Вкратце - один элемент списка - это тоже View, которое Вы можете сделать его под себя. Хоть три строки и две картинки.

Comment: @KoVadim, да я знаю, что возвращает Адаптер. Я уже работал с таким и писал собственные адаптеры. Но вот в этом случае мне нужно вернуть не один View, а ViewGroup. Так вот мне и интересно, что возвратить. Какой лучше выбрать? Потому что расчёт идёт на большое кол-во строк на главном экране.

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что ViewGroup?

Большое количество строк - это сколько? Поверьте, по тем ссылкам, что я прислал, можно сделать Вашу задачу.

Comment: Я знаю, что можно. Вы не отвечатете на мой вопрос. View подразумевает под собой контейнер под один виджет (например, картинка или текст). ViewGroup - это контейнер для большего количества виджетов. То есть можно применить LinearLayout, GridView и многие другие. Вот я и хочу определиться, что выбрать ЛУЧШЕ. Чтобы меньше памяти тратить на это. У меня и так превью почти всю память съедают. Не хочется ещё и на контейнер тратить.

Comment: Может просто неверно ставите вопрос?

Одна строка - это все таки View.

Как я бы делал - скорее всего поставил бы LinearLayout, горизонтальный, в него добавил бы картинку, ещё один вертикальный LinearLayout с двумя TextView, и в конец первого ещё один TextView для отображения кол-ва. Памяти тратить много не будет, особенно если правильно переиспользовать строки.

>> У меня и так превью почти всю память съедают.

так может не с той стороны копать начали?

Comment: @KoVadim, вот наконец-то услышал. Да, наверное, тоже сейчас с помощью пары LinearLayout'ов это сделаю. А насчёт превью не волнуйтесь. Я вчера очень много статей по этому поводу перечитал. С BitMapFactory, в принципе, разобрался и куда там память сильно тратится. Особенно помогла одна статья с Хабра. В моём случае просто довольно много картинок, вот они и съедают. То есть дело не в оптимизации.

Comment: нужно было с самого начала поставить правильно вопрос. 

>> Я вчера очень много статей по этому поводу перечитал.

а вот это уже реально страшно.

Дело как раз в преждевременной оптимизации.

Comment: Ну, возможно. Я на гуру программирования пока не претендую. Всему своё время. Просто учиться нужно не только на ошибках, но и на правильных выводах (советах).